# select database array value in interval

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, explode

I'm working on a real estate site, and have a table in database and two of the columns are "price" and "surface", where surface it's an array looking like this "100 200 350" - these are the surfaces available for rent in an office building (i have more office buildings offers).
Now, the price column is on square meter like "12" (euro/sqm).

I already have a feature to search if the input values $min and $max are per sqm;

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE price between $min and $max")
```

But if user will search for a total price range, let's say between 1000 and 2500 euro he should find in my example the offer that have 200sqm in surface array (12eur x 200sqm= 2400euro)

I need to make a select to find the offers in the given price range like:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE price * (explode somehow the surface array and get each value to compare) between $min and $max")
```

Thanks

Comment: can you tell me is price is already calculated or need to do calculation and get the price.

Comment: Exactly, for getting more answer you have to write some query or some code that already you have tried...

Comment: the total price is not calculated, i just have the price per sqm in table

Comment: Even if you figure out how to get total price, this is frankly a horrible way to achieve results using SQL. If at all possible, you should try to redesign the structure to store surface.

Comment: i do store surfaces but i can't store them in a separate field, i do it like text separated by space "surface1 surface2..."

Answer (score 0):

First I would say please make sure that you are getting an array from "Surface". Because That looks like a string.

### Example

```
$surface = array('100', '80' ,'200', '350', '10');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE price_range IN (' .implode($surface, ', '). ' )';
```